# ¿Cómo corregir este error usando el iconbitmap?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy empezando hacer interfaces gráficas en python pero al asignar la imagen que quiero poner `iconbitmap` me da error, e cambiado el formato de `ico` a otros ya que estoy en linux y tampoco funciona (la imagen esta en el mismo directorio que el código)

```
return self.tk.call('wm','iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "dicta1.ico" not defined
```

```py
import tkinter
from this import s
from tkinter import *
from turtle import right                                                                            

raiz=Tk()     

raiz.title("dicta")  

#raiz.resizable(1,1)  

raiz.iconbitmap("dicta1.ico")  

raiz.geometry("1280x720")  

raiz.config(bg="red")  

miFrame=Frame()

#miFrame.pack(side="bottom", anchor=E)   

miFrame.pack()  #(fill="y" , expand=1)

miFrame.config(bg="blue")

raiz.config(bd=30)

raiz.config(relief="groove")                 

raiz.config(cursor="spider")

miFrame.config(width="650" , height="350")

miFrame.config(bd=20)

miFrame.config(relief="groove")                 

miFrame.config(cursor="spider")

raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Si ese error se debe a que no está encontrando el archivo, puede ser que el directorio de trabajo NO sea la ubicación del script principal. Los paths relativos se completan usando el directorio de trabajo. Si en tu script agregas `import os` y luego `print(os.getcwd())` el directorio que imprime en pantalla es el directorio donde está el programa?

Comment: Hola, el directorio tiene que estar bien porque quito esa funcion y si me va el codigo. Gracias

Comment: Eso es por que esa función es la unica que depende del directorio de trabajo para obtener la imagen. El resto no depende del directorio de trabajo. Lo que te propuse hacer muestra en pantalla el directorio de trabajo actual. Te recomiendo hacer lo que propuse y decirme el resultado.

Comment: Ok, no se si sera eso lo k tenia k hacer. Gracias